# Android Espresso test consuming a lot memory while testing

Tags: android, performance, unit-testing, automated-tests, android-espresso

Test files and running on `BuddyBuild`. All test are written in Espresso. Running in Android 7.0 Nexus. All are Instrumented Tests.

I have 24 test running for my application. While running a lot of memory is consumed (~250MB) and it affects the testing code.

Android Monitoring

[image: image1]

app. is just having service calls and db calls from local and all the functionality test. This is not a gaming app. Large heap is also requested.

Android Log

[image: image2]

And because of this some view are not found and app test fails until the memory usage is decreased.

Android Logs

[image: image3]

How to decrease memory consumption ? How to close app after every test so that a fresh start will not have memory allocation , so that no test will fail ?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.test.espresso.Espresso;
import android.support.test.espresso.IdlingResource;
import android.support.test.filters.LargeTest;
import android.support.test.filters.SdkSuppress;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.declaree.declaree.activity.LogInActivity;
import com.declaree.declaree.activity.MileageActivity;
import com.declaree.declaree.util.Constants;
import com.declaree.declaree.util.Preferences;
import com.declaree.declaree.util.Utils;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

import java.util.Random;

import static android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation;
import static android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext;
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onData;
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.pressKey;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.anything;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class CreateMileageTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LogInActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(LogInActivity.class);
    private IdlingResource mIdlingResource;
    private ActivityTestRule<MileageActivity> mActivityRuleExp = new ActivityTestRule<>(MileageActivity.class);

    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    @Before
    public void grantPhonePermissionAndInitSolo() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
                    "pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                            + " android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
                    "pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                            + " android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
        }


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
                    "pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                            + " android.permission.CAMERA");
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
                    "pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                            + " android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void registerIdlingResource() {
        Utils.idle = true;
        mIdlingResource = mActivityRule.getActivity().getIdlingResource();
        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);

    }

    @After
    public void unregisterIdlingResource() {
        if (mIdlingResource != null) {
            Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void initializeSolo() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
                    "pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                            + " android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
        }
    }

    @SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = 18)
    @Test
    public void createMileageTest() {

        enterCredentialsForLogin();

        signIn();

        Utils.idle = false;

        onView(withId(R.id.ll_expense)).perform(click());

        Utils.idle = false;

        openMileageLayout();

        enterMileageData();

        enterDistanceData();

        //FOR DISTANCE PAGE
        onView(withId(R.id.action_save)).perform(click());
        SystemClock.sleep(100);

        //for main page
        onView(withId(R.id.action_save)).perform(click());
        SystemClock.sleep(100);

        mActivityRule.finishActivity();

    }

    private void enterDistanceData() {

        onView(withId(R.id.ll_distanceHolder)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.ll_fromHolder)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.action_search)).perform(click());
        onView(isAssignableFrom(EditText.class)).perform(typeText("Nagpur Railway"), pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
        onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.lv_locations)).atPosition(1).perform(click());
        SystemClock.sleep(100);

        onView(withId(R.id.ll_toHolder)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.action_search)).perform(click());
        onView(isAssignableFrom(EditText.class)).perform(typeText("Pune Airport"), pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
        onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.lv_locations)).atPosition(1).perform(click());

        Utils.idle = false;
    }

    private void enterMileageData() {

        onView(withId(R.id.et_description)).perform(typeText("Create Mileage Test->" + getRandomNumberFromRange()), closeSoftKeyboard());

        onView(withId(R.id.ll_tag1Holder)).perform(click());
        onView(withText("Internal")).perform(click());

        onView(withId(R.id.ll_tag2Holder)).perform(click());
        onView(withText("Sub 1")).perform(click());

        onView(withId(R.id.ll_tag3Holder)).perform(click());
        onView(withText("Client 1")).perform(click());
    }

    private void openMileageLayout() {
        Context targetContext = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(targetContext, MileageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_MODE, Constants.CREATE_MODE);
        mActivityRuleExp.launchActivity(intent);
    }

    private void enterCredentialsForLogin() {
        Preferences.subscribe(mActivityRule.getActivity(), true);
        onView(withId(R.id.testName)).perform(typeText("7. Create Mileage Test"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.et_mail)).perform(typeText("Username"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.et_password)).perform(typeText("Password"), closeSoftKeyboard());
    }

    private void signIn() {
        onView(withId(R.id.btn_signIn)).perform(click());
    }

    public int getRandomNumberFromRange() {
        Random r = new Random();
        return r.nextInt(20 - 2) + 100;
    }


}
```

Comment: Give some test example.

Comment: What makes you think it's a memory issue? It seems like you have an asynctask running for more than a minute.

Comment: @Be_Negative :- yes there are many async tasks in the background but it used to pass the tests earlier. When I profile the app while tests are running in my local device the GC is called almost every minute. So that slows down the test and app. This result in mismatch of touches and click. How to solve this ? Is there anything else I can do to run all the test one by one in new app mode ? How to close app after every test completely so it starts from least memory usage again for next test.

Comment: @KarolKulbaka I've added one code sample from my tests. There are many DB calls in each login, many async tasks, and a lot of operations. And I do this 24 times in all test with some other operations. What I want is that after every test application should finish and a new start should be done so that new memory allocations will be done and app should not be in background.